# Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts storme V1.2.1 in centos

Tags: apache-storm, nimbus

I have installed Storm on a Centos machine. When I start my Storm cluster, I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader
  nimbus from seed hosts [127.0.0.1]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus
  hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
```

Content of storm.yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "127.0.0.1"
storm.local.dir: "/opt/installs/storm/storm_tool/data"

nimbus.seeds: ["127.0.0.1"]
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700
 - 6701
 - 6702
 - 6703
```

Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What's in your /etc/hosts? Can you ping 127.0.0.1 successfully? Have you tried using 'localhost' instead?

Is the nimbus service up and running? If not, maybe have a look in the logs to see if there anything wrong.